# Adding edge between 2 vertices in different partitions in Azure Cosmos DB Gremlin

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I am trying to add 2 vertices to different logical partitions, then i want to connect them through an edge, but couldn't find anything online! How to do it?!

Azure Cosmos DB Gremlin API works via Partition Key (pk) by distributing data alocation based on the value of pk ... this isolates VErtices and edges by group ... the problem i'm having is ... not being able to connect to vertices from distinct groups! They show case it simple, with no example and i couldn't do it! [check image below]

[image: 2 vertices between 2 partitions]

---

Links:

- Getting the best out of Azure Cosmos DB’s scale-out Graph API aka partitioned Graph containers => https://jayanta-mondal.medium.com/getting-the-best-out-of-cosmos-dbs-scale-out-graph-api-aka-partitioned-graph-containers-bf47c240e698
- Using a partitioned graph in Azure Cosmos DB => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin/partitioning
- Partitioning and horizontal scaling in Azure Cosmos DB => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview

---

On Azure Cosmos DB Gremlin, you have to specify the Partition Key to where the Vertex is going to be stored ... tried this:

being `pk = Person_Natural_Customer_ID`

```
g.addV('Person_Natural').property('Person_Natural_Full_Name', 'Omar Ghoche').property('Person_Natural_Customer_ID', '6753902')
```

then with `pk = Object_Email_Address`:

```
g.addV('Object_Email_Address').property('Object_Email_Address_Email', 'omar@gmail.com')
```

one of the obstacles is connecting these 2 vertices that live in different logical partitions!

```
g.addE('Uses_Email').from(g.V().has('Person_Natural_Customer_ID', '6753902')).to(g.V().has('Object_Email_Address_Email', 'omar@gmail.com'))
```

the edge adding part seems to not have any effect.

How can I proceed from that?

Comment: You can only have one partition key and the values of it determine which logical partition they belong to. So you can't have a graph that has both a partition key `Person_Natural_Customer_ID` and `Object_Email_Address`. Graphs are also isolated from each other so if you created two you can't connect items between them and can't query over them.

Comment: RELATED QUESTION: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76273168/limited-connection-with-azure-cosmos-db-gremlin

Comment: @NotFound ... but how then, to edge two vertices with different pks!?

Comment: You'll need to use the same partition key property (value can of course be different). Ideally you have a partition key that represents the same value type that is always available (such as customer id). If you don't have that you could opt for a generic partition key (e.g. `partitionKey`) and use different types of values depending on the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your Gremlin API graph you define a partition key path. The value of the partition key for each vertex defines its logical partition. To create vertices in different partitions, you simply define each vertex with a different partition key value. You can then create an edge between the two vertices.

For example, assuming you have a graph with partition key path /pk, the following two traversals will each create a vertex in a different logical partition:

g.addV(‘vertex_label_1’).property(‘id’,’V1’).property(‘pk’,’pkX’)

g.addV(‘vertex_label_2’).property(‘id’,’V2’).property(‘pk’,’pkY’)

This traversal will then select the two existing vertices and create an edge between them:

g.V(‘V1’).has(‘pk’,’pkX’).addE(‘edge_label_12’).property(‘id’,’E12’).to(g.V(‘V2’).has(‘pk’,’pkY’))

Gremlin does not have transactions so it is possible that either of the addV steps may fail or that the sequentially executed traversals may beat the propagation delay for the new graph elements. If it’s possible that this can cause issues in your application, you can read this article on using idempotent queries to ensure the existence the graph elements:

https://jayanta-mondal.medium.com/cosmos-db-graph-gremlin-api-how-to-executing-multiple-writes-as-a-unit-via-a-single-gremlin-2ce82d8bf365

Comment: hello @geethathatipatri-msft, thanks for the answer, but i wanted to better understand the TRANSACTION problem with gremlin ... before migrating to serverless ... we were using Orient DB and opening, commiting and closing transactions with Tinkerpop's own interface Transaction [https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Transaction.html] ... isn't that, per se ... gremlin's implementation of transactions?! And does Azure Cosmos DB suport it?! Their documentation is confusing [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin/support]

Comment: hey @geethathatipatri-msft ... i get it now ... why transactions don't work with gremlin with Azure Cosmos DB ... as they put it "Transactions aren't supported because of distributed nature of the system." [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin/support#:~:text=Transactions%20aren%27t%20supported%20because%20of%20distributed%20nature%20of%20the%20system.%20Configure%20appropriate%20consistency%20model%20on%20Gremlin%20account%20to%20%22read%20your%20own%20writes%22%20and%20use%20optimistic%20concurrency%20to%20resolve%20conflicting%20writes.]