# Limited connection with Azure Cosmos DB Gremlin

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

Regarding the previous answer ... the connection that is working for now ... to connect with Gremlin server @ Azure Cosmos DB Gremlin API ... is via a remote.yaml file [check image below].

The limitation is, one can only connect to a specific graph at-a-time ... giving not much space (or freedom) to where store and alocate the vertices and edges (the graph per say)!

[image]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Links:

- Quickstart: Build a graph database with the Java SDK and the Azure Cosmos DB for Gremlin => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin/quickstart-java
- [Azure-Samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples)/**[azure-cosmos-db-graph-java-getting-started](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-graph-java-getting-started)**

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**remote.yaml**

```
hosts: [*********.gremlin.cosmos.azure.com]
port: 443
username: /dbs/<database name>/colls/<collection name>
password: *******************************************************
connectionPool: {
  enableSsl: true}
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV2d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
```

I would like to put a placer or variable at **<collection name>** ... so i could be able to choose in which graph collection to add my vertices and edges ... if that is possible!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I'm reading there in the links about CosmosDB and what I know of the TinkerPop driver (I am more familiar with the latter), I don't think there is much you can do but create one `Cluster` instance per "collection" that you want to connect to. This will obviously treat these different collections as different graphs but at least from TinkerPop's driver's perspective I don't think there is any other option.

Comment: danke schön @stephen!